# Modern Web Application - Design

Tags: node.js, postgresql, web-applications, frontend, backend

I am building a large web application in node.js and I'm always faced with the question 'where should the heavy lifting be done?' I was always taught that the 'logic' should always be done in the backend of the application, but with modern computers and browsers being so powerful it begs the question if some of the heavy lifting logic can go in the front end.

So context to my specific application. Using angularjs and postgres. A specific question is: would it be a bad practice to have the back end api fetch the rows from the database and pass it to the front end. And then have the front end deal with the logic of deriving the information from the rows? Things like counts with in date ranges and such. (ignore security for this question) or should all the be done on the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it deals with script that doesn't need to be hidden or is not a secret, then I would suggest putting most of it on the front-end, it would lessen the stress on your server and give you more space to run more processes at a time without filling the ram.

Comment: See that's what I was thinking but some advise that the front-end is more or less a 'view only' situation when it comes to logic.

Comment: Overall, it comes to trade-offs between the two.  For example, if you were to put all the calculations on the front-end, you would have more efficiency on server, however you lose the security aspect of relying on true information from the client side due to the possibility of the user changing it theirselves.

If you do choose to put it on the frontend, just add safe-guards to prevent someone misusing your data.

Comment: Right which is why the data that comes from the front end is validated on the backend